# Java PostProcessing of Dynamic Time Warping Output

Tags: java

I want to use the output of DynamicTimeWarping (DTW) for classification.
It turns out that the output of dynamic time warping algorithm still need post-processing.
As part of the time aligning process, some single data points of data A will be mapped into several data points on data B.
I plan to take the average of those several data points on data B where they are mapped into single data point to data A.
The final output would be one-to-one mapped data points between data that has been optimized for similarity.
Then I will use this final output for classification.

Following is my current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class dtw_postprocess {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inFile = new File ("WarpPath.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);

        {
            int a[] = new int[600];
            while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int i=0;
                a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }

            sc.close();
            File inFile2 = new File ("Data.txt");
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (inFile2);

            double[] b = new double[600];

            {
                int l=0;
                do {
                    b[l]=sc2.nextDouble();
                } while(sc2.hasNextDouble());   
            }

            sc.close(); sc2.close();


            File warped = new File("warpedOutput.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos_warped = new FileOutputStream(warped);
            BufferedWriter bw_warped = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos_warped));

            for (int m=0; m < a.length; m++){
                bw_warped.write((int) lookup(a,b));
                bw_warped.newLine();
            } 

            bw_warped.close();
        }
    }


    static double lookup (int[] a, double[] b){
        int i=0;
        while(a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i] != a[i+2] && a[i+1] != a[3]) {
            return b[i];
        }

        while(a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i] < a[i+2] && a[i+1] == a[3]) {
            double[] c = {a[i],a[i+1],a[i+2],a[i+3]};
            double d = kahanMean(c);
            return d;
        }

        while(a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i] == a[i+2] && a[i+1] < a[3]){
            return b[i-1];
        }
        return b[i];
    }

    static double kahanMean(double[] data) {
        double sum = 0, c = 0;
        int num = 0;
        for (double d : data) {
            ++num;
            double y = d - c;
            double t = sum + y;
            c = (t - sum) - y;
            sum = t;
        }

        return sum / num;
    }
}
```

The input will be two files,
Warp Path of Data A to Data B, looks like: `[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1),(5,2)]`

Data A, looks like:

```
0.243333333
0.41
0.44
0.16
0.03
0.09
```

It is supposed to write the output on `warpedOutput.txt`, but the output file produced is blank.

Comment: Did you try flushing your output stream before closing it? ie. `bw_warped.flush()`

Comment: Another thing, the `while` and `do-while` loops where you use a `Scanner` to read from a file and store the data read, in an array - You never increment the indexing variable, so each value get stored in the same index. ie. `int i = 0; a[i] = sc.nextInt();` - `i` never changes from zero. I also don't know why your using blocks `{ ... }` when they're not. needed.

Comment: Looking over your code even further - you need to read up on loops. The loops in your `lookup` method only look at `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]`. If those are the only indices you care about, then why use a `while` loop, just use an `if` statement. Even if your `while` loops did iterate over the entire array, the first loop would either not run or it would return on the first iteration, same goes for the second and third loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will read up again on loops and try it again.